# Lua: Fastest Way to Read Data

Tags: io, lua, integer

Here's my program.

```
local t = {}
local match = string.gmatch
local insert = table.insert
val = io.read("*a")

for num in match(val, "%d+") do
    insert(t, num)
end
```

I'm wondering if there is a faster way to load a large (16MB+) array of integers than this. Considering the data is composed of line after line of a single number can this be made faster?  Should I be looking at io.read("*n") instead?

Comment: It's very misleading to rename `string.gmatch` as `match`. It makes your code a lot harder to follow when function names are named different things in different places.

Comment: You're right.  I'll follow that practice in the future.  Would it be acceptable to drop string though as an indicator that the function is now local?

Comment: It would be preferable to just do `val:gmatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your file size is 16MB, your loading routine's performance will be dominated by file IO. How long it takes you to process the loaded data will generally be irrelevant next to that.

Just try it; profile how long it takes to just load the file (stopping the script after `io.read`), then profile how long the whole script takes. The latter will be longer, but it's only going to be by some relatively small percentage, not vast amounts.

Loading the whole file at once the way you're doing will almost certainly be faster than doing it piecemeal. Filesystems like reading entire blocks of data all at once, rather than bits at a time. Beyond that, how to process the text is relatively irrelevant.

Comment: Note that his operating system/C library may use buffered I/O inside of block lengths, in which case reading piecemeal is just as fast.... As I noted in other comment, theres no 'one' answer. Hence: I suggest whichever is the easiest code to read.

Comment: @daurnimator: "*Note that his operating system/C library may use buffered I/O inside of block lengths*" Then again, it may not. It may detect that he's reading a large block of data and load it all at once. So while this method may not be faster than your case, it won't be any *slower*. And since it *may* be faster, it's the better solution for performance.

Comment: It also may not, `fscanf` ( http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/liolib.c.html#read_number ) might be faster than `strtod`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if its faster, but `read("*n")` is much simpler...

```
local t = { }
while true do
    local n = io.stdin:read("*n")
    if n == nil then break end
    table.insert ( t , n )
end
```

Comment: "*I'm not sure if its faster*" Then why are you answering? He asked for "faster", not "simpler".

Comment: because there is no 'one' answer. its system dependant. this may be the fastest on some systems, others may be fastest on others.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this would be faster:

```
local t = {}
local match = string.match
for line in io.lines() do
   t[#t+1] = match(line, '%d+')
end
```

Don't forget to convert strings to numbers.

Comment: Okay. Which part makes this faster the io.lines or the different insertion of the number into the table?

Comment: Thanks by the way I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: @user1569327 - Yes, it is fastest method of appending value to an array.